# Change title given to Reading List article

Tags: safari, reading-list

I often use Safari's Reading List functionality to save links to pdf documents from the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/).  The URL for the particular paper -- and hence the title given in the Reading List -- is not very informative:

[image: example reading list]

Is there a way to change the title of the item in the Reading List?  Perhaps there is some file that stores metadata for this item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there’s no way to do it directly through the GUI, but there is a file you can edit quite easily. The file `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` contains all of the Safari bookmarks, including those saved to the Reading List. (For whatever reason, this file gets borked in TextMate, among others, but [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) seems to cope just fine).

Anything beginning `<key>ReadingList</key>` is an item saved to the Reading List. There are two entries that control the title and the description. The first will be of the form:

```
<key>PreviewText</key>
<string>No preview available</key>
```

This occurs about six or seven lines in. Change this, and the description changes. The second entry is of the form:

```
<key>title</key>
<string>http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.1763/arxiv.org</string>
```

and you can imagine what that does.

This procedure worked for me in Safari 5.1.1 in 10.7.2; I presume it should similarly work for you.

Two caveats: I have no idea what this might do to an iCloud-synced reading list. If the edit doesn’t get marked with the appropriate edit date, there could be some weird sync conflict brouhaha and Safari might explode. Also, I quit Safari while I messed around in `Bookmarks.plist`. No idea what might happen if you leave it open; probably nothing. But y’know. You can’t be too careful.

This is an example full entry for a Reading List item in `Bookmarks.plist`.

```
<dict>
    <key>ReadingList</key>
    <dict>
        <key>DateAdded</key>
        <date>2012-11-29T23:30:55Z</date>
        <key>DateLastFetched</key>
        <date>2012-11-29T23:30:55Z</date>
        <key>PreviewText</key>
        <string> **This is the short description** </string>
    </dict>
    <key>Sync</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>”C=1234567890"</string>
        <key>ServerID</key>
        <string>https://example@example.com+ABCDEFG12345</string>
    </dict>
    <key>URIDictionary</key>
    <dict>
        <key>title</key>
        <string> **A web page that I’ve saved** </string>
    </dict>
    <key>URLString</key>
    <string>http://www.example.com/readinglist</string>
    <key>WebBookmarkType</key>
    <string>WebBookmarkTypeLeaf</string>
    <key>WebBookmarkUUID</key>
    <string> 1234567890 </string>
</dict>
```